# hasClass to exclude div from container event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I try to create a button, which opens with a click event. I create a div menu inside container div named button. I try to activate button when i click in button class. However, I want to exclude the surface of the menu div  in my click event.

```
        $('.button').click(function (e) {
            if (++clickCount % 2 == 0 && !$(e.target).hasClass('menu')) {
                $('.button').animate({right:-x}, t);
            } else {
                $('.button').animate({right:x}, t);
            }

        });
```

Inside menu div i ve got 4 div items. When i click inside menu area but outside those 4 divs animation stops. However, when i click inside those items inside menu animation activates. How is it possible to exclude the whole surface of the menu div??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`hasClass` accepts the class name as an argument, but the code prefixes the class name argument with `.` as if it were a selector.

Change:

```
!$(e.target).hasClass('.menu')
```

to:

```
!$(e.target).hasClass('menu')
```

Comment: Ok I am facing another problem now, inside menu div i ve got 4 div items. When i click inside menu area but outside those 4 divs animation stops. However, when i click inside those items inside menu animation happens. How is it possible to exclude the whole surface of the menu div??